# Attached images in iPad's email

Tags: java, iphone

I'm sending emails with embedded images through java class and in iPad2 the email client shows the body information correctly, except that repeats again the images embedded below the body (it seems that attach them). The images are `.png` instead o `.jpg`.

Does anyone have any idea about this problem?.